# How do I retrieve Quickbooks inventory quantity by site using the SDK? (advanced inventory module)

Tags: sdk, quickbooks, inventory

This seems like a simple issue, but it's eluding me.  Let's say I have items A,B,C, and D and sites W, X, Y, and Z.  I want to know how many Cs there are at site X.  With ItemInventoryQuery I can retrieve the total number of Cs across all sites, but how can I get site-specific quantities?

The only method I've found so far doesn't scale well.  I can use InventoryAdjustmentQuery for item C and process through all the entries to calculate the current value, but that's going to become far too time-consuming as items are purchased,sold,transferred, etc.

Please help me discover what I'm missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way we've found to do this is with a ItemSitesQueryRq. You can filter by specific site(s) or leave it blank to get the quantities on hand for all sites.

The request looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="10.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <ItemSitesQueryRq>

            <ItemSiteFilter>
                <SiteFilter>

                    <FullName>Your Site Name Here</FullName>

                </SiteFilter>
            </ItemSiteFilter>

            <MaxReturned>25</MaxReturned>

            <ActiveStatus>All</ActiveStatus>
        </ItemSitesQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

[QuickBooks qbXML example](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_for_Querying_for_Inventory_by_Site) request from our [QuickBooks development wiki](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/Example_qbXML_Requests).

And the response you get back includes elements such as:

```
ItemInventoryRef/ListID
ItemInventoryRef/FullName

InventorySiteRef/ListID
InventorySiteRef/FullName

ReorderLevel
QuantityOnHand

QuantityOnPurchaseOrders
QuantityOnOrder
QuantityOnSalesOrders
QuantityOnSalesOrder

QuantityToBeBuiltByPendingBuildTxns
QuantityRequiredByPendingBuildTxns
QuantityOnPendingTransfers
```